# unable start debugging F5 under visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I just create a new project ( code above) under visual studio 2008 (En) :

```
int main ()
{
   std::cout <<"hello" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

when i make "build solution", the compiler create à mycode.exe. But when i make "start debugging F5", my compiler blocked. With shortcut key "ctrl + f5", i get cmd (Windows Command Prompt) !!! I tyied to launch mycode.exe separatly, there isn't any result. In both case the process mycode.exe figure in the task manager and it impossible to kill it!!!!

I don't understand what happen exactly?

Comment: thank you very much Hans. That resolve my problem but what's the impact of AVAST on VS2008?